# Como mudar a source de um image control a partir de um ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho o ResourceDictionary seguinte:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:semaforo.imagens">
<BitmapImage x:Key="semaforoVerde" UriSource="green.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="semaforoAmarelo" UriSource="yellow.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="semaforoVermelho" UriSource="red.png" />
```

Sempre que quero mudar a cor do semáforo procedo assim:

```
semaforo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/imagens/red.png"));
```

Em vez do Uri utilizado acima é possível utilizar algo mais simples como a x:Key="semaforoVerde" ou algo assim?

Comment: Você quer fazer isso no código ou no *xaml*?

Comment: No código. Ainda estou a usar a sintaxe do ""pack://application:,,,/imagens/red.png" sem ter a certeza do que é!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via código pode aceder aos *resources* declarados/definidos num *Control* de duas formas:

1 - Usando a propriedade [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
semaforo.Source = (BitmapImage) Control.Resources["semaforoVerde"];
```

2 - Usando o método [FindResource()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
semaforo.Source = (BitmapImage) Control.FindResource("semaforoVerde");
```

Substitua `Control` pelo respectivo nome do objecto onde foi declarado/definido o *resource*.
Caso tenha sido ao nível da aplicação use `Application.Current`

Comment: No meu caso era Application.Current ... funcionou na perfeição e é mais simples do que eu estava a fazer.